# Fabric Mod: BlockRenderLayerMap is not importing properly and is giving this error location: package net.minecraft.client.render

Tags: java, minecraft, fabric, minecraft-fabric

```java
import net.fabricmc.fabric.api.blockrenderlayer.v1.BlockRenderLayerMap;
import net.minecraft.client.render.RenderLayer;
```

My fabric Mod was not working properly:
Both of the imports were not importing properly, it said `error: package net.fabricmc.fabric.api.blockrenderlayer.v1 does not exist`. I am programing in java 17 and in Minecraft 1.19 (not 1.19.1), I followed my tutorial to the letter, but this issue came up in my ModClient file.

```java
import net.fabricmc.api.ClientModInitializer;
import net.fabricmc.fabric.api.blockrenderlayer.v1.BlockRenderLayerMap;
import net.lincforr.fabricmod.block.ModBlocks;
import net.minecraft.client.render.RenderLayer;

public class FabricModClient implements ClientModInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onInitializeClient() {
        BlockRenderLayerMap.INSTANCE.putBlock(ModBlocks.EGGPLANT_CROP, RenderLayer.getCutout());
    }
}
```

I tried adding the library as it suggested however it still errored out. I looked around the fabric docs, but it just told me to add the same piece of code and did not explain why the issue my occur. I was trying to make the transparent parts of my texture for the Eggplant actually transparent, they would show up in game as a white or black background instead of being transparent [here is an image of what it looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMGoJ.png).

Comment: If you need any more info let me know.